# Couldn't get the camera to work using expoTHREE and expoGRAPHICS to create an AR scene in a React-native project

Tags: react-native, three.js, expo

I am developing a React Native app and I wanted to implement a AR scene using Three.js. My project is initialized using "React-native init" and then I installed expo modules. I created a separate module called "CamTab.js" and implemented the AR scene in it. Then I called the component from MainScreen.js. I can build and run my app without any errors but camera screen does not show up as intended. CamTab.js is shown below.

I added the Text "The Text" to see if it shows up and it works.

```
onContextCreate = async ({gl, scale, width, height, arSession}) => {
    //initialize renderer
    this.renderer = ExpoTHREE.createRenderer({gl});
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(scale);
    this.renderer.setSize(width, height);

    //initialize scene
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.scene.background = ExpoTHREE.createARBackgroundTexture(arSession, this.renderer);

    //initialize camera
    this.camera = ExpoTHREE.createARCamera(arSession, width / scale, height / scale, 0.01, 1000);

}

onRender = (delta) => {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
}

render(){
    return(<View>
            <Text> The Text </Text>
        <ExpoGraphics.View style = {{flex:1}}
            onContextCreate= {this.onContextCreate}
            onRender = {this.onRender}
            arEnabled={true}/>
            </View>

    );
}
```

}

I intend to display the camera input using this component but I get nothing. just the white screen.